# Can you switch programming languages with the same database

Tags: sql, database, transfer

Say I have a python/Django website fully built. I now want to re-create that website with Ruby on Rails or some other language. Is this possible to keep the same database? Or would I have to transfer data between the two databases?

Comment: If you are using a separate database server / process like MySQL then in general the existing data is usable.  You will run into problems if your existing code used the database to serialize / deserialize custom language objects as BLOBs or textareas instead of using the native SQL fields.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Different products have different options.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to keep the same database in the new application that you used from the old. You can even have multiple applications use the same database as the same time.

However, you should not just port everything over query for query. There are likely subtleties in the old application that will be easy to miss... places where logic one would normally expect to live in the database instead lives in the application. There are also likely decisions regarding database structure that were made to accommodate quirks or abilities of the old environment that no longer make sense for the new.

The result is this a common point where you might also create a service layer. With a service layer, **neither** application talks to the database directly. Instead, they both talk to a service application that mediates access to the DB.

This new service layer helps make sure business logic is consistent across applications, without drifting between the two platforms. It helps avoid duplicating work. It helps with performance by creating an obvious place for things like a heroku caching layer, and by making it easier to scale data access across multiple servers.